# Split a column into multiple columns pandas depending on the values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below.

```
                     A          B
timestamp       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0          45
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3          NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4          30
2022-05-09 09:28:03  5          20
2022-05-09 09:28:04  8          10
```

I want the values in `column B` to be split and represented in multiple columns depending on the values in `column A` as shown below.

```
                     A_0  A_3  A_4  A_5  A_8
timestamp       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  45   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02  NaN  NaN  30   NaN  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:03  NaN  NaN  NaN  20   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  10
```

Since the splitting depends on the values present in another column and there is no delimiter present, the solution to split the column depending on a delimiter does not work.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** If I want to do it for multiple columns, for eg:

```
                     A          B       C     D
timestamp       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0          45      3     20
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3          NaN     2     15
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4          30      5     34
2022-05-09 09:28:03  5          20      4     NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04  8          10      8     NaN
```

And I want to convert to this

```
                     A_0  A_3  A_4  A_5  A_8  C_3  C_2  C_5  C_4  C_8
timestamp       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  45   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  20    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2022-05-09 09:28:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   15   NaN  NaN  NaN  
2022-05-09 09:28:02  NaN  NaN  30   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  48   NaN  
2022-05-09 09:28:03  NaN  NaN  NaN  20   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2022-05-09 09:28:04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  10   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Is this still possible or do I have to do separetly and `merge` or `concat` them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
with `append=True` for `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1=df.set_index('A',append=True)['B'].unstack().add_prefix('A_').rename_axis(columns=None)
print (df1)
                      A_0  A_3   A_4   A_5   A_8
timestamp                                       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  45.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:01   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02   NaN  NaN  30.0   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:03   NaN  NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

Or use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.reset_index().pivot('timestamp','A','B').add_prefix('A_').rename_axis(columns=None)
```

EDIT from comment under answer - use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function, default is `mean` with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add `timestamp` with missing values in `B` column:

```
print (df)
                     A     B
timestamp                   
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0  45.0 <-duplicated timestamp, A values
2022-05-09 09:28:00  0  30.0 <-duplicated timestamp, A values
2022-05-09 09:28:01  3   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02  4  30.0
2022-05-09 09:28:03  5  20.0
2022-05-09 09:28:04  8  10.0



df2 = (df.reset_index()
         .pivot_table(index='timestamp',columns='A',values='B', aggfunc='mean')
         .add_prefix('A_')
         .reindex(df.index.unique())
         .rename_axis(columns=None))

print (df2)
                      A_0   A_4   A_5   A_8
timestamp                                  
2022-05-09 09:28:00  37.5   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:01   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02   NaN  30.0   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:03   NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

---

Aggregation by `mean` used for first part of solution - row with missing values is not removed:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['timestamp','A'])['B']
         .mean()
         .unstack()
         .add_prefix('A_')
         .rename_axis(columns=None))
print (df2)
                      A_0  A_3   A_4   A_5   A_8
timestamp                                       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  37.5  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:01   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02   NaN  NaN  30.0   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:03   NaN  NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

EDIT: Dirst create pairs with same values after `_` with `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'A':'V_A', 'C':'V_C',
                        'B':'I_A', 'D':'I_C'})
```

Then use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df3 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['V', 'I'],
                     i='timestamp', 
                     j='i', 
                     sep='_',
                     suffix=r'\w+'
                     ).reset_index()
      )
print (df3)
             timestamp  i  V     I
0  2022-05-09 09:28:00  A  0  45.0
1  2022-05-09 09:28:01  A  3   NaN
2  2022-05-09 09:28:02  A  4  30.0
3  2022-05-09 09:28:03  A  5  20.0
4  2022-05-09 09:28:04  A  8  10.0
5  2022-05-09 09:28:00  C  3  20.0
6  2022-05-09 09:28:01  C  2  15.0
7  2022-05-09 09:28:02  C  5  34.0
8  2022-05-09 09:28:03  C  4   NaN
9  2022-05-09 09:28:04  C  8   NaN
```

And last aggregate `mean` with reshape:

```
df4 = (df3.groupby(['timestamp','V','i'])['I']
          .mean()
          .unstack(['i','V'])
          .sort_index(axis=1)
         )
df4.columns = df4.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df4)
                      A_0  A_3   A_4   A_5   A_8   C_2   C_3  C_4   C_5  C_8
timestamp                                                                   
2022-05-09 09:28:00  45.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  20.0  NaN   NaN  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:01   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  15.0   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02   NaN  NaN  30.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  34.0  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:03   NaN  NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Both results in "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I belive unstack fails when the column contains NaN values.  The dataframe is quite huge and I have presented just a sample of it.

Comment: @GGEng - error means there are multiple rows with same `timestamp, A` values. So solution is aggregate this duplicates values, e.g. by `mean` if use instead `df1 = df.reset_index().pivot('timestamp','A','B').add_prefix('A_').rename_axis(columns=None)` pivot_table like `df1 = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='timestamp',columns='A',values='B', aggfunc='mean').add_prefix('A_').rename_axis(columns=None)`

Comment: @GGEng - added to answer with explanation.

Comment: Thank you. The columns of B is split based on the values in A. If I want to do it for multiple columns, for eg: Split D based on C, Is it possible to do it with one line of code?

Comment: @GGEng - if need `C` with `D` then need same solution like above with replace `A->C`, `B->D`. If need `f I want to do it for multiple columns, for eg: Split D based on A` then it is possible by change `.pivot_table(index='timestamp',columns='A',values='B', aggfunc='mean')` to `.pivot_table(index='timestamp',columns='A',values=['B', 'D'], aggfunc='mean')`

Comment: @GGEng solution was reaacepting, whats happens? EDIT part not working for you, because not exist in another answer, which is acceped?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) would only work when there is no duplicated combinations for timestamp/A :

```
df.reset_index().pivot('timestamp', 'A', 'B').add_prefix('A')
```

output:

```
                      A_0  A_3   A_4   A_5   A_8
timestamp                                       
2022-05-09 09:28:00  45.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:01   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:02   NaN  NaN  30.0   NaN   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:03   NaN  NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN
2022-05-09 09:28:04   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0
```

If you have duplicated indices you need to decide on how to handle it. Either aggregate using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) or deduplicate the duplicates first:

output:

```
(df.reset_index()
   .pivot_table(index='timestamp', columns='A', values='B',
                aggfunc='sum') # chose the method to aggregate, default is 'mean'
)
```

Comment: my second solution?

Comment: posted 52 minutes ago?

Comment: @jezrael obviously I hadn't seen the second part ;) Anyway I answer mostly for the pivot_table part that I just added